# Datamatrix can only be read if centered on the screen with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation for a barcode scanner which must scan type datamatrix, but if it is not centered on the preview image it is not scanned, for example if the label with the datamatrix is at the top of the screen it cannot be scanned.

This my input device configuration

```
captureDevice.LockForConfiguration(out _);
captureDevice.FocusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus;
captureDevice.ExposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure;
captureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration();
```

Preview and session

```
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.FromSession(_captureSession);
previewLayer.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill;
captureView.Layer.AddSublayer(previewLayer);
previewLayer.Frame = captureView.Bounds;
previewLayer.LayoutIfNeeded();
captureView.LayoutIfNeeded();
var con = previewLayer.Connection;
con.VideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait;
_captureSession.CommitConfiguration();
_captureSession.StartRunning();
outputMetadata.RectOfInterest = previewLayer.MapToMetadataOutputCoordinates(View.Frame);
```

Comment: Make sure that you set the direction of Datamatrix correctly . Here is a sample that maybe can help you https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/ios11/AVCamBarcode/AVCamBarcode .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT In this example, the same thing happens, the label has to be in the center of the yellow rectangle. It does not matter in which position I to place the rectangle since it is adjustable, I have to center the datamatrix

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Sorry I had not responded, I was out. this gist contains the viewDidLoad where I set up and DidOutputMetadataObjects https://gist.github.com/luistejadaa/7f101c83ccb88ce0e7b23b1914ecf25d

Comment: You could try to use Frame instead of  AutoLayout .It works fine on my side .